# How to increase aws amplify build timeout?

Tags: aws-amplify

My web build is very intensive due to the fact that I am using a full static prerendering build with many pages.

I tried overriding `BUILD_TIMEOUT` environmental variable to `180` in my AWS amplify dashboard (under "Environmental variables"), but still hangs at min 30.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the var env should be named `_BUILD_TIMEOUT`-